# Re: I want to draw a dynamic views based on the X and Y Coordinates and height and width of every view

Tags: android, dynamic, view, coordinates

I want to draw a dynamic views based on the X and Y Coordinates and height and width of every view. Lets take a example like a function hall with lot of tables. so i want to draw all tables like a Button based on X and Y and height and width.

The main problem i am facing here is Android devices has different screen resolutions right. how can i do this any idea please help me.

And i want this view clickable views.

Please see the image below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom View, you will get the height and the width of the view in pixel on the OnMeasure.
Then you will be able to draw the table at the right place on the OnDraw.
Finally you will be able to detect touch event on your tables on the OnTouch.

Here is a tuto about Custom View, but you can find many others on google.
http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-custom-view-tutorial-part-2-custom-attributes-drawing-and-measuring/

Comment: thanks for your reply, i checked the link what you sent but this link is not similar to me to do that task what am i asking @sypotu

Answer (score 0):

You could use a GridView with X and Y dimensions. Create an object for each gridViewLocation which can hold int x and int y to save the location, and store the objects in a HashMap as the key to easily obtain the items in a given location. From here, you can use displayMetrics to get the width and height of the screen to edit the dimensions of the objects placed in the GridView.

To adjust for screen size dynamically, you can hardcode the screen size you're testing on (for example, your screen width could be X and your screen height could be Y, find these numbers with displayMetrics when debugging). Then, just calculate X2/X1 and Y2/Y1 (where X2 and Y2 are the screen dimensions of the current device, X1 and Y1 are your dimensions), and multiply those fractions by the initially desired width and height. Set the layout accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your reply, gridview has properties like number of columns, but in my case some space entire column/row should be empty..How can i do it i have X and Y values how can i calculate X and Y with my screen and i want fit all ietms into that view..  @Steeno

Comment: Just going off of the sketch you drew above, you can put frame layouts in empty positions in the grid when you need it to be empty or change the parameters. Use: `FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams` and you can set the width and height accordingly for a specific row and column. As for X and Y calculations, you go off of what I said above. Take the screens height and width using `DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics` and `dm.widthPixels` with `dm.heightPixels`. Just decide how many columns and rows you would like, and take that fraction of the display metric.